# Trigger creating multiple records but only need 1

Tags: apex

I am trying to create a new record and copy fields from the old record when a field is updated. The trigger fires as expected but it is creating 2 record not just a single record.
As always, thanks for your time and help..
M

```
trigger SalesProgramNew on Sales_Program__c (after update) 
{
 List<Sales_Program__c> spnew=new List<Sales_Program__c>();
     for(Sales_Program__c spold : Trigger.New)
     {
           if(spold.Early_Buy_PY_Total__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(spold.id).Early_Buy_PY_Total__c)
           {     
                  Integer newDate = Integer.valueOf(spold.Current_SBF_Year__c) +1; 
                  string snewdate = string.valueOf(newDate);
                  Sales_Program__c s = new Sales_Program__c();
                  s.sales_Program_Type__c =spold.Sales_Program_Type__c;
                  s.Account__c = spold.Account__c;
                  s.JDE_Number__c = spold.JDE_Number__c;
                  S.Early_Buy_PY_Total__c = spold.Total_YTD_Indirect_Sales__c;
                  s.Current_SBF_Year__c = snewDate;
                  spnew.add(s);
            }
           /// if(spnew.size()>0)
            insert spnew;
     }   


}
```

Comment: you are inserting Sales_Program__c inside an Sales_Program__c  after insert trigger?

Comment: Do you have a workflow rule on `Sales_Program__c` with a field update? That's a common cause (if not the most common) of `Update` triggers running multiple times.

Comment: I have ran the above code on other object and it is creating a single record. So there is something that is making the trigger to run multiple times.

Comment: @Rao, each Sales Program is associated to an Account.  So each Account will many SP records.  At the end of this year I will capture a final value that will populate a field(Early_Buy_PY_Total__c).  I then want to create a new SP record associated to the same Account using values from the prior years SP record.  I am hoping this will work when its done in a mass update.  Also it was a bloody work flow causing my issue.  Thanks everyone for the very fast responses.

Comment: The WF is performing calculation on the SP.  Why is causing the trigger to create 2?  The reason I ask is that I need the WF to run if at all possible.  Thanks. M

Comment: How has no one mentioned dml in a `for` loop? That's a very bad idea.

Comment: @AdrianLarson thank for the heads up.  I have moved the dml outside of the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your issue is that you have a workflow rule on `Sales_Program__c` that is running a field update.

If you take a look at the [Salesforce Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm), about halfway down we see

> 12. If the record was updated with workflow field updates, fires before update triggers and after update triggers one more time (and only one more time), in addition to standard validations. Custom validation rules, duplicate rules, and escalation rules are not run again.

This explains why you're getting 2 records when you only expect 1. **Your `AfterUpdate` trigger is being run twice**.

This is just how Salesforce works, *there's nothing you can do to prevent your trigger from running twice*.

If you can't prevent your trigger from running twice, you need to find a way to prevent the code in your trigger from running twice. This can be accomplished by using a static variable, and moving the code currently in your trigger into a separate Apex class.

In its simplest form, most of the work you need to do is literally copy and paste.

```
public with sharing Class CreateExtraSalesProgram{
    private List<Sales_Program__c> spnew = new List<Sales_Program__c>();

    // new, static variable
    // If you're certain that you'll only be calling this class once per transaction,
    //   then you could change this to a boolean instead of a set.
    // A set is required to handle situations where you update more than 200 records
    //   at a single time.
    private static Set<Id> alreadyProcessed = new Set<Id>();

    public void run(){
        
        // We need to clone Trigger.newMap to do what we do next
        Map<Id, Sales_Program__c> copyOfNewMap = Trigger.newMap.deepClone();

        // This is the magic that makes this all work.
        // removing records from a map's keyset will remove the key (and
        //   the value as well, since a map value can't exist without a key)
        // If we remove the records that we know we have processed before, that
        //   leaves us a map of records that we know have not yet been processed.
        copyOfNewMap.keySet().removeAll(CreateExtraSalesProgram.alreadyProcessed);

        // Instead of using trigger.new, we use the filtered copy of trigger.newMap
        for(Sales_Program__c spold : copyOfNewMap.values())
        {
            // One last change, now that we're processing new records, we need 
            //   to add those Ids to our set of processed Ids.
            CreateExtraSalesProgram.alreadyProcessed.addAll(copyOfNewMap.keySet());

            if(spold.Early_Buy_PY_Total__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(spold.id).Early_Buy_PY_Total__c)
            {     
                Integer newDate = Integer.valueOf(spold.Current_SBF_Year__c) +1; 
                string snewdate = string.valueOf(newDate);
                Sales_Program__c s = new Sales_Program__c();
                s.sales_Program_Type__c =spold.Sales_Program_Type__c;
                s.Account__c = spold.Account__c;
                s.JDE_Number__c = spold.JDE_Number__c;
                S.Early_Buy_PY_Total__c = spold.Total_YTD_Indirect_Sales__c;
                s.Current_SBF_Year__c = snewDate;
                spnew.add(s);
            }
        }
    
        // DML should not appear inside of a loop
        // I've taken the DML outside of the loop to make the code bulk-friendly
        insert spnew;
    }

}
```

Your trigger then becomes

```
trigger SalesProgramNew on Sales_Program__c (after update) 
{
    CreateExtraSalesProgram extraSalesProgram = new CreateExtraSalesProgram();
    extraSalesProgram.run();
}
```

This sets you up nicely to move to start using the trigger handler pattern, which is considered best practice. [There is a document in Salesforce's technical library](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices) that goes over the benefits, and how to start working towards using trigger handlers.

The reason why you can't just do this in the trigger is because static variables inside of triggers behave differently than static variables anywhere else. Normally, a static variable will retain its value throughout the entire transaction. In a trigger, however, static variables are reset after each invocation of the trigger.

If you tried to do this inside a trigger (as opposed to a separate apex class), it simply wouldn't work.

### +edit:

As is, there are a few problems with my example code that make it not compile. As far as I can tell, this is because Salesforce is doing some magic behind the scenes.

Trigger.newMap, Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap, and Trigger.old are all normally collections of `sObject`.

It's only a guess, as I can't find concrete documentation for this, but, it appears that when inside of a trigger, Salesforce has enough information to implicitly cast the trigger context collections to a more concrete type (`Map<Id, Sales_Program__c>`, and `List<Sales_Program__c>`). Anywhere else, besides triggers, we can't use the normal dot-notation to get at specific fields of generic `sObjects`.

You can go through, and do things like `Trigger.oldMap.get(<someId>).get('<some field name>')` or `Map<Id, Sales_Program__c> myMap = (Map<Id, Sales_Program__c>)Trigger.newMap.deepClone();` but at that point it becomes more sensible to pass these things as arguments.

This is a pretty simple change, and can be thought of as a form of Dependency Injection. I'll leave out most of the unchanged code.

```
public with sharing Class CreateExtraSalesProgram{
    private List<Sales_Program__c> spnew = new List<Sales_Program__c>();

    // No changes outside of the run() method

    // Simple change to accept a few parameters
    public void run(Map<Id, Sales_Program__c> oldMap, Map<Id,Sales_Program__c> newMap){

        // Now that we're getting data from method arguments, we can (and should)
        //   drop the 'Trigger.' part of Trigger.newMap.deepClone()
        Map<Id, Sales_Program__c> copyOfNewMap = newMap.deepClone();

        // No changes required for the loop definition itself
        for(Sales_Program__c spold : copyOfNewMap.values())
        {
            // unchanged code omitted

            // Likewise, we should drop 'Trigger.' from the call to oldmap now.
            if(spold.Early_Buy_PY_Total__c != oldMap.get(spold.id).Early_Buy_PY_Total__c)
            {     
                // unchanged code omitted
            }
        }

        // unchanged code omitted
    }

}
```

The trigger code changes just a little bit too, since we now need to pass arguments to the `run()` method

```
trigger SalesProgramNew on Sales_Program__c (after update) 
{
    CreateExtraSalesProgram extraSalesProgram = new CreateExtraSalesProgram();

    // By passing trigger.oldMap/newMap to the run method, we retain the advantage
    // of getting more-concrete trigger context variables
    extraSalesProgram.run(Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.newMap);
}
```

This answer is getting a bit long-winded at this point, but moving to this pattern has another, big advantage. You can potentially (with a bit more work) test the `run()` method *independently of testing your trigger* making them closer to true 'Unit' tests. In certain situations, it's also greatly simplified the test setup that I've needed to perform. I think getting too much into that is a bit too far out of scope for this question though.

### +edit 2:

In chat, we've been going over lingering issues.

There is workflow that is running which causes a field update to occur on the newly inserted record, which ends up causing duplicates to be inserted (still).

The solution here is to catch the record being created (and inserted) by `extraSalesProgram.run()` and add it to our `alreadyProcessed` set so that when the workflow field update causes this new record to go through an update operation, we can prevent it from creating another, undesired record.

Since we need to capture the Id of the new record, and we need to do so before the `Update` triggers run, our only option is to do work `After Insert`.

The only change to the trigger is that we add `after insert`

```
trigger SalesProgramNew on Sales_Program__c (after insert, after update) 
{
    CreateExtraSalesProgram extraSalesProgram = new CreateExtraSalesProgram();

    // By passing trigger.oldMap/newMap to the run method, we retain the advantage
    // of getting more-concrete trigger context variables
    extraSalesProgram.run(Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.newMap);
}
```

The change to the run method amounts to about 3 extra lines of code

```
public void run(Map<Id, Sales_Program__c> oldMap, Map<Id,Sales_Program__c> newMap){

    // The only thing that we want to do if this method is called in an after update
    //   trigger is to add the Ids to our alreadyProcessed set.
    // We want to skip all other processing.
    // Using Trigger.isAfter/isInsert makes this code more dependent on being run
    // from a trigger, which is less than ideal, but acceptable.
    // The general concept of using if statements towards the beginning of a method,
    //   to prevent executing more code is known as a 'guard clause'
    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert){
        extraSalesProgram.alreadyProcessed.addAll(newMap.keySet());
        return;
    }

    // From this point on, we know that we aren't running in an after insert context.
    // However, since we do add Ids to our alreadyProcessed set when called
    //   after insert, those newly-inserted records will be removed from
    //   copyOfNewMap and thus won't have yet another Sales_Program__c record
    //   generated for it.
    Map<Id, Sales_Program__c> copyOfNewMap = newMap.deepClone();

    // unchanged code omitted
}
```

Comment: for everyone else, yes, I know, this is also an opportunity to do some Dependency Injection, and me not using it in my example makes the helper class more tightly coupled to the trigger. It would be a simple addition, but my goal here was to somewhat limit the scope of my answer, and make the general approach more friendly. DI would help, but isn't strictly necessary for this to work.

Comment: thank you for the very thorough answer.  Annotation is always helping in regards to understanding what is being presented.  I tried the code you provided but it has thrown an error.  **Illegal assignment from Map<Id,SObject> to Map<Id,Sales_Program__c>**.                                                       The error is on this line of code:    Map<Id, Sales_Program__c> copyOfNewMap = Trigger.newMap.deepClone();

Comment: Didn't think that would be an issue here. This is easy enough to fix though, you need to cast the result of deepClone to a more specific type. `(Map<Id, Sales_Program__c>)Trigger.newMap.deepClone()` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Derek,  @Derek F changing the line of code to    Map<Id, Sales_Program__c> copyOfNewMap = (Map<Id, Sales_Program__c>)Trigger.newMap.deepClone();

Comment: But this caused a new error : "Field expression not allowed for generic SObject".  at line *if(spold.Early_Buy_PY_Total__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(spold.id).Early_Buy_PY_Total__c)*

Comment: Again, another issue I didn't think would pop up. Looks like there's some background magic that Salesforce does when accessing trigger context variables from within a trigger. It seems like doing Dependency Injection is looking viable now (which I'll edit into my answer after I finish researching a bit more). To get this working now, you could just use the sObject `get()` method like so `Trigger.oldMap.get(spold.id).get('Early_Buy_PY_Total__c')`.

Comment: That did it.  Derek, how is the code formatting performed when posting a comment?  I want to post the final result so that others can see the entire solution.  Thanks again for your help and explanations....M

Comment: I thought I was good but the trigger  is throwing an error: *Variable does not exist: CreateExtraSalesProgram.spnew*

Comment: Comments aren't a good place for code, and my goal wasn't so that everyone can just copy/paste the solution. Rather, I aim to give enough context and explanation so that others can hopefully understand how a solution actually works (so they can take the base I provide, and modify it to suit their needs). Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47017/discussion-between-derek-f-and-michael).

Answer (score 0):

Just put the " insert spnew;" after 2nd closing brace, means outside of the "For Loop". Performing a DML operation inside a loop isn't good idea.